# How to exclude dependency from Plugin in gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am using springboot version 2.4.6 and gradle version 6.3. This springboot downloads commons-compress 1.20 and I want to exclude this particular version of commons-compress. I want to have commons-compress 1.21 for security reasons. I have enforced this particular version by using :

```
implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-compress') {
        version {
            strictly '1.21'
        }
    }
```

However when I do gradle build, it shows me both 1.20 as well as 1.21. So how do I exclude commons-compress 1.20 in the Plugin?

This is how my code snippet:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "2.4.6"
        junitVersion = "5.7.2"
        awsVersion = "1.11.728"
        lombokVersion = "1.18.12"
        resilience4jVersion = "1.7.0"
        logbackJsonVersion = "0.1.5"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "checkstyle"
    id "com.github.spotbugs" version "4.4.4"
    id "idea"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    id "jacoco"
    id "java"
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.4.6" --> this is the culprit
    id "pmd"
}

dependencies {

    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-compress') {
        version {
            strictly '1.21'
        }
    }
.....
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            additional = ['deployTag': System.getenv('DEPLOY_TAG') ?: '']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One cannot exclude any dependency from a Gradle plugin, but only upgrade the plugin.

Version `2.5.4` might not have it and Gradle is currently also rather version `7.1.1`.

Comment: I already tried with 2.5.4 but it did not help either